# Link 3 values/types in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 3 types, (TCPClient, string, class)
Note that the class is defined at a different time to the others

I would like these to be linked together, i.e. I have 1 of these values and can get the others from that - something similar to Hashtables but with 3 values instead of 2

I have thought about multidimensional arrays, but i have been told in the past to avoid these if possible

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Can you try and re-phrase it?

Comment: It's abit vague... what about a class with 3 fields ?

Comment: Have you seen [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) ?

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, my command of English (despite being native) is not good at explaining things :L
However:
re: class: why did i not think of that?
re: tuples: there is an answer below
re: rephrasing: i wil try

Comment: Actually I don't think this question was vague - I've read far worse here on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the 3 are related in some way and work together for one purpose, so how about putting them in a class and using a List of that class?

Answer (score 3):

In recent version of the .NET Framework you can use the `Tuple<>` generic class like:

```
List<Tuple<TCPClient, string, object>> items = new ...;

items.Add(new Tuple<TCPClient, string, object>() { Item1 = ..., Item2 = ..., Item3 = ... });
```

And to find an item you could use LINQ like:

```
var item = (from i in items where i.Item2.Equals("Test") select i).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please note that this is in no way equally efficient as a `Dictionary`. Another solution would be to simple create three `Dictionary`s with respective key types to which you add a `Tuple` that holds instances of the respective other two types.

You could wrap this up into a separate class, so you don't need to remember to manage all thee `Dictionary`s when adding or removing items.

Comment: I'm seeing the keyword `class` in a place that I'm not used to seeing it. Does that compile? <--- No, it does not.

Comment: No, it won't compile, but the answer is correct nonetheless -- the OP just needs to substitute `class` with whatever his real class name is.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll replace that with `object`. Also, I'm just outlining things, so...